# Remove text up to (inclusive) second to last period (or `://` if only one period)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following data:

```
http://123.456.789.10.com
http://789.12340.com
http://456.789.1123123rs.com
http://12321.com
```

What I'm trying to do is get the text up to the second to last period. for example, the formula should return these values:

```
10.com
12340.com
1123123rs.com
12321.com
```

Note: If there is only one period (as in the last example) I want to get rid of everything up to (inclusive) the `://`.

I tried: (value is stored in D2 cell)

`=RIGHT(D2,FIND(".",D2,FIND(".",D2)+1)-1)` (which doesn't work well when using RIGHT, but it does works perfectly when using LEFT)

`=RIGHT(D2,FIND(".",D2)+1)`

I don't know what am missing...

Can someone help?

Comment: Your examples conflict with your description of the problem.

Comment: From the second period from left, or from right?

Comment: @MarianD  To add on to MarianD's question, and what do you want when there is only one period?

Comment: So, just to verify ... Do you want the text after the second period from the left, or do you want the text after the second period from the right? i.e. Does `http://0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.arenumbers.com` become `2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.arenumbers.com` or does it become `arenumbers.com`?

Comment: arenumbers.com is the output that I am looking for.

Comment: Also, according to your before/after data sets you don't want to include the `http://` at the beginning in cases where there is only one `.`. Will your data *always* have an `http://` (or similar protocol, ending in `://`) at the beginning of it, which is not to be included?

Comment: for now, it is correct. http:// is there, but I can easy remove that to have only 0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.arenumbers.com if that makes it easy for the formula to work.

Comment: @MarianD: If I'm not mistaken, it's not impossible to do what @​MrServer wants, just difficult to be certain exactly what @​MrServer really wants.

Comment: I already have a formula, I just want to verify: Does any of the data you're trying to process not contain `://`? or is it all contain unwanted `://`? Your answer may mean I need to change my formula slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the following formula will do what you want:

**Brief summary of algorithm:**

*use the formula evaluation tool to tease it apart and see how it works in detail. As noted in the comments, you will see that the **`99`** puts a limit on the number of characters you can return. This might have to be altered if your returned data might be longer*

- remove everything up to and including `://`
- replace the 2nd from last dot with a rarely used character
- use the `FIND` function to locate that substitution so as to generate the Start number for the `MID` function

---

```
=MID(A1,FIND("://",A1)+2+FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE("." &MID(A1,FIND("://",A1)+3,99),".",CHAR(1),LEN("." &A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("." &A1,".",""))-1)),99)
```

[image]

Comment: Your use of `CHAR(1)` is a good idea, but this doesn't work if the end result is *very* long, as it truncates it at 99 characters.

Comment: @3D1T0R It works for the examples given.  If you have longer end results in your own data, you should change that value so the string will not be truncated.

Comment: I don't have data that I feel needs this, just pointing out an issue with it so that if someone has very long data they can see that this will not work well for them.

Comment: @3D1T0R OK.  I have different expectations of the audience. I think your comment might have been useful had you written, instead, something indicating that that parameter might need to be adjusted for very long data. Instead, I indicated that the reader should use the formula evaluation tool to examine the specifics.  By doing so, they should be able to figure that out for themselves.

Comment: You could easily fix the issue I was pointing out by replacing `99` with `LEN(A1)`, then the maximum length of the result would be the length of the original text, and thus will always be at least as long as (actually longer than) the actual result.

Comment: @3D1T0R Your last comment is useful; much more so than your first.

Comment: My first comment was primarily meant to inform you that your formula could be improved. If you fixed it, I would delete my comment. In the event that you do *not* fix it, it serves to inform people who use this formula that they may not be getting what they expect. It's likely that a person with data that would trigger the truncation issue in their dataset may copy & paste the formula, see that it works as expected for a chunk of their data, then later have issues with their new dataset because of it. Hopefully if this happens they kept their original data as well.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I put a comment on my own answer as well detailing a couple of possible issues. One of which I plan to fix, and described the fix in the comment so that if someone runs into the problem before I get to fixing it in the answer, they can see how to fix it for themselves. The other is an issue with the method used and can only be solved by using a different method. (Which I may or may not add to my answer [or as another answer] in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT(D2, 
 LEN(D2) - FIND("\", SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "\", LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "")) - 1))
```

---

**The explanation:**

First, we get the *number of periods* with this simple trick:

1. We determine the *length of the the full text*:
   `=LEN(D2)`  *(see column `E` in the picture)*
2. We determine the length of the same text but with *all periods removed*:
   `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", ""))` *(see column `F` in the picture)*
3. The *difference* will be the *number of periods*:
   `=LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", ""))` *(see column `G` in the picture)*

Second, as we know the *number of periods*, we are able to determine the
*occurrence number of the last but one period*. For example, if number of periods
is `5`, the last but one period has the occurrence number `4`:

- `=LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "")) - 1` *(see column `H` in the picture)*

Third, we use this as the *4-th parameter* of the SUBSTITUTE() function
*to replace that occurrence of period  with the `\` symbol:*

- `=SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "\", LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "")) - 1)` *(see column `I` in the picture)*

Fourth, we determine the position of that symbol (`\`) with the FIND() function:

- `=FIND("\", SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "\", LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "")) - 1))` *(see column `J` in the picture)*

Fifth, as we know the *position of that symbol (`\`)* and the *length of the full text,*
we may determine the *number of remained symbols*, i. e. symbols *after* `\`. For examle, 
if the length of the full text is 5 and the position of `\` is 3, there are 2 remained symbols:

- `=LEN(D2) - FIND("\", SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "\", LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "")) - 1))` *(see column `K` in the picture)*

Finally, we use it as the second parameter of the `RIGHT()` function:

- `=RIGHT(D2, LEN(D2) - FIND("\", SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "\", LEN(D2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2, ".", "")) - 1))` *(see column `L` in the picture)*

and **it is the final formula**.

[image]

---

*Note:*

The last example in the question has *no second but one period* (in contradiction with the title of the question). To include such possibility, add `.` after `http://`, i. e. substitute all `D2` in formula with

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D2, "//", "//.")
```

Comment: Note: This will mess up if your data contains ``\`` characters after the `://`. If you use this formula, I recommend using @RonRosenfeld's trick of using `CHAR(1)` instead of ``\``, as it's *much* less likely that your data is going to contain the "Start of Heading" character than a ``\``.

Comment: @3D1T0R, the backslash character (\\) *is not allowed* in URIs, and so nor in URLs - see Chapter 2 (Characters) in [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean that there can't be backslashes in someone's data. Others may come here in the future that aren't looking to use this with URLs, and they may have backslashes, or other unexpected characters in their data, but it's less likely that they'll have characters that can't be typed directly typed on a keyboard, and *very* unlikely that they'll specifically have the "Start of Heading" character in their data unless it's corrupted, in which case there are other things they should do with their data before they process it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The usual formula uses `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace all the characters of interest, the period in this case, with strings that are arbitrarily long compared to the data one could reasonably find in a cell.

For example, if the longest a set of characters between periods could be is, oh, 95 in your expected data, then a replacement string of, say, 250 "spaces" replacing each period would work nicely.

Then wrap the `SUBSTITUTE()` function in a `RIGHT()` function. If your result should only be 3 characters long, you need 253 characters at the right. You have 502 before you pick up anything undesired. If the full 95 expected plus 250 spaces plus another 95 will result, you need 420 characters to cover yourself. But still have 502 you can take without taking undesired characters. So pick a number between the max you expect, 420 and the mas you can use, 502:  perhaps 490, and take the rightmost 490 characters with the `RIGHT()` function.

Now wrap the `SUBSTITUTE()` function around that, this time replacing spaces with "" so all the spaces introduced go away and you have your desired result.

If spaces can be in the desired result, use a different character which won't be. Something odd looking in the font's list of possible characters. Perhaps ¬ (Alt-01452). Or don't risk it and use that instead of ever using spaces.

Don't type out 250 spaces either. Use the `REPT()` function in the first (interior) `SUBSTITUTE()` function to type the character of choice once but get 250 of them!

There are other approaches but they usually involve knowing how many of the character there can be. For instance, your data could be well-formed enough to know there are always 4 periods. Then these work nicely. But if it could vary, 3 here, 7 there, well...

The above is "brutal" rather than "elegant" but who really cares? Simple in conception so easy to use and it does your trick.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "", 2)), SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)*2)), " ", "."), IFERROR(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("://", A1)-2), A1))`

## How does this work?

First we have an `IF` statement that lets us treat things differently if there's one (or less) periods, or if there are at least 2 periods.

Our logical test is to check if there's a second period: `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "", 2))`
This will return `0` if it can't find 2 periods in the string, or `1`) if there are 2 or more.

We then put the 'if there are 2 or more periods' formula first, and the 'if there are less than 2 periods' formula second, but since the latter is much simpler, I'll cover it first.

#### If there are less than 2 periods:

If there is one or zero periods, then we need to remove the text up to and including the `://` at the beginning, so we'll find the position of the `://` and take only the text after it: `RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("://", A1)-2)`
Just in case there is data that doesn't start with a protocol ending in `://` we should wrap this with an `IFERROR` and get the whole original string instead of a `#VALUE` error, this ends up being: `IFERROR(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("://", A1)-2), A1)`

#### If there are (at least) 2 periods

Now that we have the simpler cases out of the way, lets look at what happens when there are 2 (or more) periods: `SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)*2)), " ", ".")`

Let's break that down:

1. We replace all periods with a large number of spaces (as many as there are characters in the whole original string): `SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", REPT(" ", LEN(A1)))`
2. We take only the end of that, specifically twice the length of the original string. This gives us the last two parts, and a bunch of spaces before and between the 2 parts: `RIGHT(<step 1>, LEN(A1)*2)`
   Note: If you wanted to include the next section as well, you'd change `*2` to `*3`.
3. We remove all the extraneous spaces using `TRIM`, leaving us with only a single space, where the one remaining period is supposed to be: `TRIM(<step 2>)`
4. We replace that one remaining space with a `.`: `SUBSTITUTE(<step 3>, " ", ".")`

So our whole formula is:
`=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "", 2)), SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)*2)), " ", "."), IFERROR(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("://", A1)-2), A1))`

Comment: You can also use the "Not" character instead of the space (as suggested by @Roy in his answer) by replacing `" "` with `CHAR(172)` in both places where it is used, thus preventing some issues that could occur due to data containing spaces. (Note: There could still be some issues if your results *needs* to contain multiple spaces next to each other.)